# Adding NONCLUSTERED index to a temp table on Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-synapse

can someone confirm if I can create nonclustered index on a temp table in Azure Synapse? I keep getting the

> "Cannot create a non-clustered index on a temporary table"

error and don't find any text on Microsoft documents regarding limitations on creating indexes on temp tables.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, only `non-clustered indexing` isn't supported on temporary tables in Azure Synapse Analytics.

All initial index configurations are available on temp tables i.e., `HEAP` | `CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX` | `CLUSTERED INDEX`. You need to choose any of these indexing for your temp tables.